# np.save and np.load with memmap mode returned OSError

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-memmap

I tried this simple code:

```
import numpy as np
np.save('tmp.npy', np.empty(128))
tmp = np.load('tmp.npy', mmap_mode='r+')
np.save('tmp.npy', tmp[:64])
```

It returned `OSError`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 4
      2 np.save('tmp.npy', np.empty(128))
      3 tmp = np.load('tmp.npy', mmap_mode='r+')
----> 4 np.save('tmp.npy', tmp[:64])

File <__array_function__ internals>:180, in save(*args, **kwargs)

File c:\Users\User\Documents\KULIAH\LAB_SOFTWARE\python_proj\anagrambotid\.venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py:518, in save(file, arr, allow_pickle, fix_imports)
    516     if not file.endswith('.npy'):
    517         file = file + '.npy'
--> 518     file_ctx = open(file, "wb")
    520 with file_ctx as fid:
    521     arr = np.asanyarray(arr)

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'tmp.npy'
```

My OS is Windows 11, I think on linux it would be worked fine. What happened here?

Even using `tmp.flush()` changes nothing.

Comment: You opened (mem-mapped) the `tmp.npy` in read-only mode and you try to write into it simultaneously which does not make sense. AFAIK Windows locks files while Linux does not, but this operation would cause an undefined behaviour on Linux anyway : you may read data that is written regarding the caching of the page coming from the mem-mapped file. Put it shortly, you need to save data in a different file.

Comment: `np.save` will accept an open file instead of a filename.  I don't know how that will work with your memmap file.